# C++/SDL Overwriting an array some how?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, sdl

I am creating a game engine for a project and am using SDL for input and stuff.

I have something like this:

```
class CInput
{
public:
    CInput();

    Rect MousePosition      = Rect(0, 0);
    Rect MouseDeltaPosition = Rect(0, 0);

    bool GetMouseButton(int button);

    bool Process();

private:
    bool _mouseButtons[5];
};

bool CInput::GetMouseButton(int button)
{
    return _mouseButtons[button - 1];
}
```

The rect structure is like this:

```
struct Rect
{
    int x, y;

    Rect(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};
};
```

I am logging the mouse buttons and movements to be used for well whatever really, but it seems that when I set the mouseposition/mousedeltaposition it is "overflowing" onto the _mouseButtons array?

Here is my input capture:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        MousePosition      = Rect(event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
        MouseDeltaPosition = Rect(event.motion.xrel, event.motion.yrel);

        break;

    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        _mouseButtons[event.button.button - 1] = true;
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        _mouseButtons[event.button.button - 1] = false;
        break;

    case SDL_QUIT:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

During testing, the _mouseButton arrays can get filled with 255 even though nobody is pressing a button.

EDIT---

[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoADc.png)

This is from simply doing: Input.GetMouseButton(0)
that returns 255 when the mouse is in a certain position

!!! I have narrowed down the issue, it appears to occur when DeltaMousePosition.y is negative, as in the mouse is moving upwards in relation to the window! Could be the problem

Comment: It probably _is overflowing_ because you lied to the compiler that the variables are const.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: This is minimal, and it's complete for the problem....

Comment: Hard for us to compile and test..

Comment: Literally nothing really more I can give you other than function names...

Answer (score 0):

```
const Rect MousePosition      = Rect(0, 0);
// ...
*(Rect*)(&MousePosition)      = Rect(event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
```

You told the compiler that MousePosition was const. Its not a reference and not a pointer, so the compiler **knows for sure**, that `MousePosition.x` and `MousePosition.y` can never change, which means, they are `0`. From now till eternity, they will be `0`.

If the compiler optimizes your code the way I expect it to, it will just remove `MousePosition` and `MouseDeltaPosition` completely and replace all reads from `MousePosition.x`, `MousePosition.y`, `MouseDeltaPosition.x` and `MouseDeltaPosition.y` with a literal `0`, this is why you're writing in your array instead.

TLDR: Don't lie to the compiler. If you are writing to a variable, don't make it const and cast away constness.

Edit:

> This is from simply doing: Input.GetMouseButton(0) that returns 255 when the mouse is in a certain position

Well, take a look at that function:

```
bool CInput::GetMouseButton(int button)
{
    return _mouseButtons[button - 1];
}
```

`0 - 1` is `-1` so reading from `_mouseButtons[-1]` reads the data *from somewhere else*. Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I have now removed the const, and am still getting the issue. Updated post

Comment: The enum starts at 1, so there is no 0 with the mouse button

Comment: @ReeceWard "there is no 0 with the mouse button" yet in question you said that you do use 0 as test case. One of these is wrong. If you do use value within [1;5] range then the problem isn't in presented code.